# What does "per then" here mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

> All products were protected under the previous laws. For the next 5 years a bill that would replace the 1906 revised law was stalled in Congress. It took tremendous effort to pass new standards enforceable by the FDA. In 1937 a Tennessee drug company advertised a new sulfanilamide elixir specifically aimed toward children. The toxic solvent was untested ( **per then** current laws) and more than 100 people, mostly children, died. It was later determined that the solvent was similar to antifreeze, which is deadly to humans.

I couldn't find it while looking it up in dictionaries. Is it suitable for this text? I mean can you use it in different examples, please?

Answer (score 1):

> (**per then** current laws)

means (**according to** then current laws), meaning that any testing would be  according to the standards in place at that time In this case, it seems that testing was not required.

See the definition of [***per***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/per)

> 3) according to (used esp. in business)   ⇒ *"per your instructions"*

*then current laws* is a separate phrase, meaning *laws current at that time*.

Comment: It might make things clearer if you hyphenate then-current.

Comment: What @WhatRoughBeast wrote or *any* way of showing what *really* goes together - brackets, removal of the bold **per then**...

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I wasn't trying to grammar check the original quote, just trying to explain it. Without the source I would not try to explain that.

Comment: @user3169 - My point was that the bolding suggests that OP was under the impression that "then" stood alone as a noun. In this phrase, however, "then" is an adverb which modifies "current", and "then-current" would make the connection easier for an English learner to appreciate.

Comment: Concur, this is correctly written "then-current laws".